# is translating frequentist results to a chain of bayesian models scientifically sound?

Tags: probability, distributions, bayesian, experiment-design

Let us say that we have available a catalog of known frequentist models.

For example:

- continuous variable coagulation time $CT$
- linear regression on outcome $CT$ for the predictor transfusion $T$
- linear regression on outcome $CT$ for the predictor fresh frozen plasma administration $FFP$.

We can compute $P(CT>x | T)$, and we could also do it for the event sequence $P(CT>x | T, FFP)$, assuming no interaction between $T$ and $FFP$, but I would like the probability distribution instead.

I aim at representing the event sequence as a program and compute the probability distribution of $CT$ after each event and also the full event sequence. The literature only makes available summary statistics describing the distribution of $CT$ before the event, and model parameters such as regression coefficients.

Given that I do not have access to the raw data, is the translation of a sequence of events as above to a sequence of bayesian models something viable? Could you give me a hint about how to proceed?

Comment: It is unclear to me what the statistical meaning of guideline is...

Comment: @Xi'an well guidelines can be represented as sequences of instructions. For example: if the patient bleeds more than x -> transfuse 2 blood units -> if bleeding continues -> give fresh frozen plasma -> ... etc., with multiple steps and branching. For example : https://www.rch.org.au/clinicalguide/guideline_index/Diabetes_Phone_Call_Hypoglycemia_flowchart/